# Is my if statement/code-test correct Swift

Tags: swift

My instructor said that this code test should evaluate to:

```
 parrotTrouble(isTalking: true, hour: 6) → true
 parrotTrouble(isTalking: true, hour: 7) → false
 parrotTrouble(isTalking: false, hour: 6) → false
```

In xcode, mine is true, false, true.
With the code given, this seems true. I'm not sure, though. What am I doing wrong if anything?

Question:
"We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return true if we are in trouble."

```
 func parrotTrouble(isTalking: Bool, hour: Int) -> Bool {

    if hour < 7 {
        return true
    } else if hour > 20 {
        return true
    } else {
    return false
    }
}



parrotTrouble(isTalking: true, hour: 6)
parrotTrouble(isTalking: true, hour: 7)
parrotTrouble(isTalking: false, hour: 6)
```

Comment: You never look at the `isTalking` parameter. You can use `&&` to combine two booleans with the AND operation (TRUE if both sides are TRUE -- FALSE otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `isTalking` as well as the hour:

Here's the real simple version:

```
func parrotTrouble(isTalking: Bool, hour: Int) -> Bool {
    return isTalking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20)
}
```

The longer version:

```
func parrotTrouble(isTalking: Bool, hour: Int) -> Bool {
    if isTalking {
        if hour < 7 {
            return true
        } else if hour > 20 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `return isTalking && !(7...20 ~= hour)`, slightly shorter? :p (accidentally removed my comment)

Comment: See my update to make it clear. I was simply showing the body of your method.